# Cookie Container doesn't bound with Set-Cookie response header

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, webclient, cookiecontainer

OK guys so the issue is that I have following code:

```
HttpWebRequest req;
HttpWebResponse resp;
// go to the site
req = NetLogHttpWebRequestFactory.Create("http://www.facebook.com/");            
resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

So `resp.CookieContainer` and `resp.Cookies` are empty, but `resp.Headers["set-cookie"]` contains corresponding cookies:

```
datr=oMjsTlmv7Z1aIDOEVnIA11tQ; expires=Mon, 16-Dec-2013 16:51:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly,reg_fb_gate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com,reg_fb_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
```

If I'm going wrong with thinking that `resp.CookieContainer` should contain appropriate cookies listed above?

Thanks, guys!

---

**UPDATE**

I also tried the cookie container bug fix code listed in question [CookieContainer bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1537490/799007) but it also doesn't give a valid result bwcause it's should be called before system uses `CookieContainer` but it empty at that moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to initialize CookieContainer property of request object

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name +  " = " +  cookie.Value);
    }
}
```