# HttpWebRequest is not sending all cookies

Tags: .net, vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to have my application perform a login action on an external website. I use the following code:

```
Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim Data As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest

    req = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create(URL), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    req.Method = method
    req.CookieContainer = CookieJar

    req.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    If method = "POST" Then
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Data = enc.GetBytes(PostData)
        If Data.Length > 0 Then
            req.ContentLength = Data.Length
            Dim newStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
            newStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
            newStream.Flush()
            newStream.Close()
        End If
    End If

    Dim Response As Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)

    Dim ResponseStream As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), enc)
    Dim Html As String = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd()

    Response.Close()
    ResponseStream.Close()

    Return Html
```

What works:

- The responses have all the proper "Set-Cookie" headers
- The container saves all the right cookies (5 in total)

What doesn't work:

- All cookies are correctly being retrieved by the container. But not all cookies are sent along whith the next request. 4 cookies are set correctly but the most important one is not sent.

The cookie that is not send is this one:

```
Set-Cookie: mpSecurity="ODc2NzM2ODoxMzUODViNTg5OWM1NTNlOWMwYmMxYjUxNWZjYzJjOGQyZGU4MTc2M2M=";Version=1;Path=/;Domain=.xxxxx.nl;Discard
```

The only difference between this cookie and the cookies that are correctly sent is that this one has "Version=1" and "Discard" in it...

Does anybody have any idea why all retrieved cookies are sent except for the one above?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common known bug in CookieContainer : [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047669/cookiecontainer-bug) ***for .Net version below 4.0***

Notice the Domain of Set-Cookie Header:

```
Cookie # 1 -> Set-Cookie: mpSecurity="ODc2NzM2ODoxMzUODViNTg5OWM1NTNlOWMwYmMxYjUxNWZjYzJjOGQyZGU4MTc2M2M=";Version=1;Path=/;Domain=marktplaats.nl;Discard
Cookie # 2 -> Set-Cookie: mpSecurity="ODc2NzM2ODoxMzUODViNTg5OWM1NTNlOWMwYmMxYjUxNWZjYzJjOGQyZGU4MTc2M2M=";Version=1;Path=/;Domain=.marktplaats.nl;Discard
```

Cookie #1 is sent when the URL format is like `http://marktplaats.nl/...`
Cookie #2 is sent when the URL format is like `http://www.marktplaats.nl/...`

### Hence the problem

---

#### Here the solution # 1: (better and easy one)

```
    class DomainComparer : StringComparer
    {
        public override int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x, y);
            }
            if (x.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                x = x.Substring(4);
            }
            if (y.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                y = y.Substring(4);
            }
            return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x, y);
        }

        public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
        {
            return Compare(x, y) == 0;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
        {
            if (obj.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                obj = obj.Substring(4);
            }
            return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this is a hackfix for microsoft bug, where cookies are not shared between www.domain.com and domain.com
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cc"></param>
    static void ImproveCookieContainer(ref CookieContainer cc)
    {
        Hashtable table = (Hashtable)cc.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "m_domainTable",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, cc, new object[] { });
        var comparerPreperty = table.GetType().GetField("_keycomparer", 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (comparerPreperty != null)
        {
            comparerPreperty.SetValue(table, new DomainComparer());
        }
    }
```

Implementation of Solution # 1, whenever you create a instance of CookieContainer just call the method once

```
void main()
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    ImproveCookieContainer(ref cookieJar);
    // then use it with the WebRequest object
}
```

---

#### Here the solution # 2:

1. Don't use .Add(Cookie), Use only .Add(Uri, Cookie) method.
2. Call BugFix_CookieDomain each time you add a cookie to the container or
   before you use .GetCookie or before system use the container.

   ```
   private void BugFix_CookieDomain(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
   {
       System.Type _ContainerType = typeof(CookieContainer);
       Hashtable table = (Hashtable)_ContainerType.InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField |
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                                  null,
                                  cookieContainer,
                                  new object[] { });
       ArrayList keys = new ArrayList(table.Keys);
       foreach (string keyObj in keys)
       {
           string key = (keyObj as string);
           if (key[0] == '.')
           {
               string newKey = key.Remove(0, 1);
               table[newKey] = table[keyObj];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

All Credit for the solution to [CallMeLaNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047669/cookiecontainer-bug)

Comment: there is one more solution, which i have in my PC somewhere [looks like lost atm] will update the post once i find it!

Comment: Thanks for the effort AppDev but both solutions don't make a difference. I also noticed that another cookie from the same request, with the same domain is actually sent correctly in a subsequent request. Could it have something to do with the version or discard tag?

Comment: havent seen or heard the Discard tag, so cannot day, well is the cookie not being sent or there is some different issue?

Comment: Must be a different issue then, but I can't really define what it is much better than my description in the question.

Comment: @kay10 - its very clear from the description, + i have handled the same issue in past, and solun # 1 worked for me, well do one thing, if possible backup ur proj, upgrade to .net 4.0 is issue remains same then there is some different problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Decided to post another workaround for this/a similar case, in case someone finds it useful.**

I've had the same problem, received three cookies, only two were showing up as being sent from the next web request. I did some debugging and found that the error for me wasn't the domain itself as the previous answer suggests - in my case the problem was that *the third cookie that was returned and was not reused in the subsequent requests was set on an HTTPS redirect*, and it had the "Secure" property set to true. So ***all I had to do was to change the next request url from http://.... to https://....***, then all cookies were sent over, and everything worked.

Hope it helps someone!