# HttpWebRequest not reliably sending cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, jsessionid

I have a script that interacts with a 3rd party web site. It's been in use for over a decade without issue, until about a week ago. My script hasn't changed, I suspect the 3rd party web site did, although the strange behavior seems to emanate from HttpWebRequest.

The web site sets a JSESSIONID cookie, with the following properties:

```
Name: JSESSIONID
Value: [snip]  
Domain: n.server.com  
Path: /Am  
Secure: True  
Http only: True  
Expires: 0001-01-01 00:00:00  
Expired: False
```

The cookie is correctly sent for several requests, including:

```
POST https://n.server.com/Am/Fq/Pi
PUT  https://n.server.com/Am/Fq/P/D
```

But on the second call to

```
PUT  https://n.server.com/Am/Fq/P/D
```

(same URL, different post payload), JSESSIONID is no longer sent. The cookie hasn't changed, the URL hasn't changed.

If, right before the second call, I re-create the cookie and change its path to "/" instead of "/Am", then it is correctly sent again.

This appears different than what the answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14523811/68936) suggest; it is not a matter of changes in the server name (www vs no www) or protocol (http vs https).

Why isn't the cookie reliably sent with its original "/Am" path?

Comment: And the server definitely hasn't rewritten the cookie/replaced it with a new one that is defective in some regard?

Comment: That's correct - I looked at the HTTP headers in fiddler, there is no new SET COOKIE for  JSESSIONID from the server. I also logged the JSESSIONID cookie properties in my code right before the failing call, and it looks identical to what it was before the previous (successful) call. The server does set a new x-sess-uuid cookie, but it does that in every response and shouldn't affect the JSESSIONID cookie. Thanks for giving this some thoughts though.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` is deprecated, why not use `HttpClient`?